# Why does visiting a non <PrivateRoute> page clear my persist:polls authentication?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist to keep track of the user token, and PrivateRoutes to allow access to the main dashboard. The persist:polls is stored in the local storage with a JWT token. If I only click on routes marked as  everything works as expected, however once I click on something like "Privacy Policy" which isn't private, my local storage persist:polls is reset.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with PrivateRoute, redux-persist, or something else entirely? Here is my store.js file:

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from 'redux'
import {createFilter} from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist'
import {routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import apiMiddleware from './middleware';
import rootReducer from './reducers'

// This is helpful: https://github.com/edy/redux-persist-transform-filter
export default (history) => {
    const persistedFilter = createFilter(
        'auth', ['access', 'refresh', 'username']
    );

    const reducer = persistReducer(
        {
            key: 'polls',
            storage: storage,
            whitelist: ['auth'],
            transforms: [persistedFilter]
        },
        rootReducer
    );

    // This is used for setup here: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#usage
    // This was copied from ds-rebuild folder.
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

    // Add thunk to handle error: "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."
    const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        {},
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware, thunk, routerMiddleware(history)))
    );

    persistStore(store);

    return store
}
```

And here is my PrivateRoute

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as reducers from '../reducers'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: reducers.isAuthenticated(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute);
```

Finally, here is my main App router

```
function LandingApp() {
    return (
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/(app|profile)" component={App}/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Theme1}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login1}/>
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp1}/>
                <Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy}/>
                <Route exact path="/tos" component={Terms}/>
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    )
}

export default LandingApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wrap my routers in PersistGate

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistStore(store)}>
            <LandingApp/>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```